# What is the total number of tables that you can use in dynamodb free tier?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Ignoring capacity as my tables won't exceed 25 GB, since I have 25 RCU and 25 WCU free per month, does that mean I can have a maximum of 25 tables with 1RCU and 1WCU per table?

For my own development and learning purposes I may not need more tables, but for the sake of understanding, if I create the 26th table, then would I exceed the free tier?

Comment: I’d be surprised if you actually needed more than 25 tables just for learning. Even 3 tables should be enough for any kind of didactic purposes and for most production use cases too. Of course in production you would presumably want to use more than a few units of capacity but that’s another point

Comment: @MikeDinescu I'm new to NoSQL, so i'm not sure how many tables are actually required. Usually in RDBMS the number of tables run into 10s if not 100s for applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/):

> **Amazon DynamoDB**
>
> - 25 GB of storage
> - 25 Units of Write Capacity
> - 25 Units of Read Capacity
> - Enough to handle up to 200M requests per month

The free tier is applied as a pricing discount. The first usage of the above quantities each month has no cost.

So, yes, you could create 25 tables with 1 RCU, 1 WCU and 1GB of storage each and this would stay in the free tier. Any usage beyond this amount would be charged a normal rates.

Comment: Do the 25 units of WCU and RCU apply as per-month limit or they are the total numbers within free tier?Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JohnRotenstein. When you say "Any usage beyond this amount would be charged a normal rates", does that mean if you tried to do say 10 reads in a second, you would get charged for that? Or would the reads beyond the provisioned capacity be throttled?

Comment: @rangfu You select the capacity units for each table. Usage would be throttled to those limits (plus some burst capacity). Therefore, if you stay within those capacity unit allocations, there would be no additional charge. However, I'm not sure how DynamoDB Auto Scaling would impact the capacity units (if auto scaling is activated).

Comment: Thanks very much @JohnRotenstein. I'd like one last clarification if you have a moment. If a table is set to 1 RCU and you try to read a 5kb item (exceeding the 4kb limit per RCU), would that fail every time, or result in a charge? For simplicity, let's assume that there is no remaining burst capacity.

Comment: @rangfu If there is no burst capacity, no auto scaling and no "on-demand" setting, and the throughput exceeds the allocated RCU, then the Read request would be throttled. There would be no additional charge.